# Get video from BLOB and play that video

Tags: c#, sql, oracle11g

I am working on oracle 11g. I created a table which have 3 columns, SQL for create table is

```
create table blobvideo(fileid int,filename varchar2(100), filedata blob);
```

My code to insert video in that table is

```
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:\videoPath.mp4");
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(videoFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] fileToByte = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(fileToByte, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

        String strSQL = "INSERT INTO blobvideo (FileId,filename,FILEDATA) VALUES (1,'" + fi.FullName + "',:TEXT_DATA)";

        OracleParameter parmData = new OracleParameter();
        parmData.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parmData.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Blob;
        parmData.ParameterName = "TEXT_DATA";
        parmData.Value = fileToByte;

        OracleCommand cm = new OracleCommand();
        cm.Connection = myConnection;
        cm.Parameters.Add(parmData);
        cm.CommandText = strSQL;
        myConnection.Open();
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
```

My code to get BLOB is

```
        OracleCommand ocmd1 = new OracleCommand("select * from blobfile ", myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();
        OracleDataReader rds = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
        rds.Read();
        OracleBlob newBlob = rds.GetOracleBlob(2);
```

Insertion is working well, but my question is how can i get that video and how can i play that video in windows media player or vlc or any other video player that works with C#.

Comment: Is there a reason you're `INSERT` is into Table `Blobvideo` but doing `SELECT` on Table `blobfile`?  Also, you're always inserting `1` into `FileID`, is that not a PK?

Comment: Okay. For testing i am inserting 1 in FileID. I'll convert it to unuque numbers after that

Comment: Your first question is not clear to me

Comment: You're inserting into a different table than you're selecting from: `INSERT INTO blobvideo...` `select * from blobfile ...` is that intentional?

Comment: OH sorry, that is mistake it must be "select from blobvideo"

Comment: i got same proble like u, cannot play video from blob file. have you solve the problem?